# Custom error message удаление лишних полей

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

В rest api решил сделать custom exception handler через `@ControllerAdvice` . И хотел, чтобы клиент получал, например, лишь 3 поля моего класса `Exception` . В клиентской части имеется следующий код:

```
  try {
        ResponseEntity<> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, Example.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        System.out.println("++++"+ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
++++{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"handleMethodArgumentNotValid","fileName":"CustomExceptionHandler.java","lineNumber":49,"className":"net.thumbtack.school.netexam.serverexception.CustomExceptionHandler","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"handleException","fileName":"ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java","lineNumber":169,"className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke0","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":-2,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":62,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":43,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"Method.java","lineNumber":498,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doInvoke","fileName":"InvocableHandlerMethod.java","lineNumber":209,"className":"org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeForRequest","fileName":"InvocableHandlerMethod.java","lineNumber":136,"className":"org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeAndHandle","fileName":"ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java","lineNumber":102,"className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doResolveHandlerMethodException","fileName":"ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java","lineNumber":404,"className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doResolveException","fileName":"AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java","lineNumber":61,"className":"org.sp
```

Возможно ли в респонсе оставить только поля класса моего `Exception`, а остальные убрать(cause,stackTrace и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно вам помочь:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class HandlerExceptionController {

    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "message";

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> exceptionHandler(ValidationException exception) {
        Map<String, Object> responseException = new HashMap<>();
        responseException.put(STATUS, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value());
        responseException.put("errors", exception.getErrors());
        responseException.put(MESSAGE, exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseException, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Если я выбрасываю свое исключение, то данный способ работает. А если я хочу переопределить исключение, которое возникло при валидации? В самом валидаторе я добавляю такую строку        `context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("wrong length").addConstraintViolation();` . Затем в классе обработчика исключений перехватываю `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, ну и здесь уже возвращаю респонс со своим классом исключения. Но сообщение, которое приходит клиенту остается неизменным. То есть там опять полный набор лишних для меня полей.

Comment: Вы можете добавить в map все поля, которые вам нужно с переопределение ого исключения.